# EF Core - A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I am using `EF Core 2.1` and I am trying to update multiple entities in one go by using `Tasks` (TPL):

```
public async Task UpdateAttendance(IEnumerable<MyEvents> events)
{
    try
    {
        var tasks = events.Select(async entity =>
        {
            await Task.Run(() => Context.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.Attendance).IsModified = true);
            await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        });

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message ?? ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

But this throwing the below error.

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
```

How do I address this?

Comment: You really need change entity state async? Its does not make sense for me.

Comment: Changing `IsModified` is not long-runnning!

Comment: I guess it's not a good idea to call `SaveChanges` many times.  It's better to update all the entities and call it just one time.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that. EF Core (as was EF 6 before) is not thread-safe.

You **have** to await a task before starting the next one

```
var tasks = events.Select(async entity =>
{
    await Task.Run(() => Context.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.Attendance).IsModified = true);
    await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
});

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Here you are starting multiple tasks in parallel and awaiting them. You will have to loop over it

```
foreach(var entity in events) 
{
    Context.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.Attendance).IsModified = true;
});
await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

It am not really sure why you want to save it event-by-event (hence, the example changed to do all the modified flags before calling `SaveChangesAsync()`), as its pretty inefficient. It makes more sense to update all of the properties, then run SaveChanges in the end, since EF Core will save all changed/tracked entities when you Save the Changes. Also easier to do a roll back when something goes wrong (Operation within SaveChangesAsync happens within a transaction scope)

Comment: But neither I am getting any error nor the value is reflecting in Db

Comment: Do you even have done changes to your model? `:IsModify` will only force an update of the model, but if the value before are unchanged you'll just see the same data as after the update

Comment: Yes.while debug I have added quick watch & check the value of Attendace, I see the desired value

Comment: Why do set it manually actually? Do the entities come in a detached state (i.e. via WebApi call)? Usually EF Core tracks changes automatically when fetched from database (and tracking isnt explicitly disabled)

Comment: Sorry! I didn't get you. but here adding details. In the one request, I am fetching the Db Entitiy, doing some BL & attendance property is updated & then need to save it

Answer (score 2):

You could get multiple instances of DbContext, there are two ways to do that.

**Using [IServiceScopeFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicescopefactory?view=aspnetcore-2.2) interface (Recommended)**

In `MyRepository`:

```
private readonly IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory;
        public MyRepository(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
        {
            this.serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        }

        public async Task UpdateAttendance(IEnumerable<MyEvents> events)
        {
            try
            {
                var tasks = events.Select(async entity =>
                {
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
                        {
                            var context = scope.GetRequiredService<YourContextType>();
                            context.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.Attendance).IsModified = true;
                            await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        }
                    });
                });
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //You really should not do this, did you have a look to ILogger?
                //If you only wants to stop when an exception gets thrown you can configure VS to do that, Debug menu -> Windows -> Exception Settings
                throw new Exception(ex.Message ?? ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }
```

**Or change the DbContext life time (scoped by default) to trasient**

In `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(
    ServiceLifetime.Transient,
    options =>  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SomeConnectionStringName")));
```